# What is best way to convert DWG to KML using ArcGIS or alternatives?

Tags: kml, google-earth, arcgis-desktop, dwg

What's the best way to convert Dwg file to Kml ?

i have tried to convert Dwg file to shape file then convert it to KML, but i hadn't very good result , i had some shift from where should be seen in google earth, i heard about some software performs better than others.

i would like to know also the reasons of the shift, the DWG file used contains projected coordinates.

Comment: When you convert to a shape file does it contain the same coordinate system as the original dwg?  You might need to redefine the projection first within ArcGIS. I'm not sure if the embedded projection gets read by ArcGIS.

Comment: yes i convert it with the same coordinates system

Comment: How much of a shift is there?

Comment: Are you looking for a free or commercial solution?  Have you looked at FME?

Comment: any good solution , but i have not yet tried FME , that's could be better than arcgis solution ?

Comment: FME is pretty much the commercial leader in converting data formats.  There are many great tools to help you manipulate the data.  But it's not particularly cheap.

Comment: is there any open source alternatives ?

Comment: [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be: using FME. But you have to know the crs of the data in you dwg. Then in fme you simply drag the dwg to the workspace, add a destination dataset, and link them via reprojector transformer (use your dwg crs for source crs and LL84 for destination crs). Some features from dwg may not be supported in kml, so i would throw a geometry filter before the reprojector filter outnwhat i needed. Theres options to copy labels to the kml feature names as well if ud like to know

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much of your data  shift in Google Earth .If you talk about Huge shift , for example your shapefile seen on ocean or another country, the problem is your coordinate system.you should change your coordinate system. Try GCS-WGS1984 or another universal coordinate systems. If the shift is small, for example about 100 meters from original place of GoogleEarth Images, the problem is Uncertainties in Spatial data.Notice that Google Earth is not a nice source to locate  small scales Spatial data ( for example 1:200 or 1:1000).The user also must know about source of data preparation. The best Spatial data ( vector or raster) have uncertainties(Errors,Vaguness,...) ,thus it's up to you to correct or modify your data or not .

Answer (score 0):

I've used Plex.Earth for this task. It's commercial, but it does the job for any object.

Answer (score -2):

try this to use readkml2 in Tbn2cad, Available at autodesk exchange apps :

https://apps.autodesk.com/ACD/pt/Detail/Index?id=525570879147558726&appLang=pt&os=Win32_64